# finding modules which uses my rpm

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

I have a rpm X installed on my machine . I have several modules in my system . 
I want to check out which all modules are using the capabilities of my rpm X .

What is a simple way to find which all modules require my rpm X ?

Comment: `rpm -q --whatrequires X`

Comment: It is used to display which packages require the specified capability . My is a different case . I have in a different folder some binaries which uses the rpm . I want to find which are those binaries

Comment: Can you define what `uses` mean? For example, if your rpm X is a shared library, and you want to know which binaries are linked against it, then you can use `ldd <binary file name> | grep  libXname`. You can even use wildcard like `ldd /path/to/some/binary/*`. Note: please do not use require when you don't mean package require. It is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out module belonging to which rpm with following command:

[root@monitor01 ~]# rpm -qf /lib64/ld-2.5.so

glibc-2.5-118.el5_10.2

For your requirement you need to make script. first list out installed modules using lsmod, parse out with first column,then find out path of each module & give it to above query.